# How to count distinct fields in mongodb java Api

Tags: distinct

I need to find count of a distinct field. I used MongoCollection.distinct() which returns DistinctIterable. But it does not have any size method. To find the size I need to iterate DistinctIterable and find the size. Is there any method by which I can find the size of the distinct field values with out iterating it?

```
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("test");
DistinctIterable disIterable =collection.distinct("name");
int count =0;
Iterator iterator = disIterable.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {

iterator.next(); 
count = count +1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try use it !!

```
public long returnSize(){
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("test");
DistinctIterable disIterable =collection.distinct("name");
return disIterable.into(new ArrayList<>()).size()
}
```